# My feature column becomes null in the dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark, machine-learning, linear-regression

I am new in spark and I need to do some machine learning on my data and predict the "count" value. Here is my raw data:

```
05:49:56.604899 00:00:00:00:00:02 > 00:00:00:00:00:03, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 10202: 10.0.0.2.54880 > 10.0.0.3.5001: Flags [.], seq 3641977583:3641987719, ack 129899328, win 58, options [nop,nop,TS val 432623 ecr 432619], length 10136
05:49:56.604908 00:00:00:00:00:03 > 00:00:00:00:00:02, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 66: 10.0.0.3.5001 > 10.0.0.2.54880: Flags [.], ack 10136, win 153, options [nop,nop,TS val 432623 ecr 432623], length 0
```

I made a dataframe with columns of time_stamp_0, sender_ip_1 and receiver_ip_2 using the following code:

```
  val customSchema = StructType(Array(
  StructField("time_stamp_0", StringType, true),
  StructField("sender_ip_1", StringType, true),
  StructField("receiver_ip_2", StringType, true)))

///////////////////////////////////////////////////make train dataframe
val Dstream_Train = sc.textFile("/Users/saeedtkh/Desktop/sharedsaeed/Test/trace1.txt")
val Row_Dstream_Train = Dstream_Train.map(line => line.split(">")).map(array => {
  val first = Try(array(0).trim.split(" ")(0)) getOrElse ""
  val second = Try(array(1).trim.split(" ")(6)) getOrElse ""
  val third = Try(array(2).trim.split(" ")(0).replace(":", "")) getOrElse ""

  val firstFixed = first.take(first.lastIndexOf("."))
  val secondfix = second.take(second.lastIndexOf("."))
  val thirdFixed = third.take(third.lastIndexOf("."))
  Row.fromSeq(Seq(firstFixed, secondfix, thirdFixed))
})
val Frist_Dataframe = session.createDataFrame(Row_Dstream_Train, customSchema).toDF("time_stamp_0", "sender_ip_1", "receiver_ip_2")
val columns1and2 = Window.partitionBy("sender_ip_1", "receiver_ip_2") // <-- matches groupBy


///I add count to the dataframe
val Dataframe = Frist_Dataframe.withColumn("count", count($"receiver_ip_2") over columns1and2)
Dataframe.show()
```

Here is the output:

```
+------------+-----------+-------------+-----+
|time_stamp_0|sender_ip_1|receiver_ip_2|count|
+------------+-----------+-------------+-----+
|    05:49:56|   10.0.0.2|     10.0.0.3|   19|
|    05:49:56|   10.0.0.2|     10.0.0.3|   19|
|    05:49:56|   10.0.0.2|     10.0.0.3|   19|
|    05:49:56|   10.0.0.2|     10.0.0.3|   19|
|    05:49:56|   10.0.0.2|     10.0.0.3|   19|
|    05:49:56|   10.0.0.2|     10.0.0.3|   19|
|    05:49:56|   10.0.0.2|     10.0.0.3|   19|
|    05:49:56|   10.0.0.2|     10.0.0.3|   19|
|    05:49:56|   10.0.0.2|     10.0.0.3|   19|
|    05:49:56|   10.0.0.2|     10.0.0.3|   19|
|    05:49:56|   10.0.0.2|     10.0.0.3|   19|
|    05:49:56|   10.0.0.2|     10.0.0.3|   19|
|    05:49:56|   10.0.0.2|     10.0.0.3|   19|
|    05:49:56|   10.0.0.2|     10.0.0.3|   19|
|    05:49:56|   10.0.0.2|     10.0.0.3|   19|
|    05:49:56|   10.0.0.2|     10.0.0.3|   19|
|    05:49:56|   10.0.0.2|     10.0.0.3|   19|
|    05:49:56|   10.0.0.2|     10.0.0.3|   19|
|    05:49:56|   10.0.0.2|     10.0.0.3|   19|
|    05:49:56|   10.0.0.3|     10.0.0.2|   10|
+------------+-----------+-------------+-----+
```

I would like to predict the number of connections between two IPs. I added count to the dataframe. I also try to make label and feature to start predictions. I also need to spilt the data for training and testing part. I used the following code:

```
    val toVec4    = udf[Vector, Int, Int, String, String] { (a,b,c,d) =>
      val e3 = c match {
        case "10.0.0.1" => 1
        case "10.0.0.2" => 2
        case "10.0.0.3" => 3
      }
      val e4 = d match {
        case "10.0.0.1" => 1
        case "10.0.0.2" => 2
        case "10.0.0.3" => 3
      }
      Vectors.dense(a, b, e3, e4)
    }

    //val encodeLabel   = udf[Double, String]( _ match { case "A" => 0.0 case "B" => 1.0} )

    val final_df = Dataframe.withColumn(
      "features",
      toVec4(
        Dataframe("time_stamp_0"),
        Dataframe("count"),
        Dataframe("sender_ip_1"),
        Dataframe("receiver_ip_2")
      )
    ).withColumn("label", (Dataframe("count"))).select("features", "label")

final_df.show()

    val trainingTest = final_df.randomSplit(Array(0.3, 0.7))
    val TrainingDF = trainingTest(0)
    val TestingDF=trainingTest(1)
    //TrainingDF.show()
    //TestingDF.show()
```

**However the problem is the feature becomes null!**

```
+--------+-----+
|features|label|
+--------+-----+
|    null|   19|
|    null|   19|
|    null|   19|
|    null|   19|
|    null|   19|
|    null|   19|
|    null|   19|
|    null|   19|
|    null|   19|
|    null|   19|
|    null|   19|
|    null|   19|
|    null|   19|
|    null|   19|
|    null|   19|
|    null|   19|
|    null|   19|
|    null|   19|
|    null|   19|
|    null|   10|
+--------+-----+
```

Can anybody help me to solve the problem. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that your UDF expects the four input columns to be of types `Int, Int, String, String`, and you're passing a `String` as the first column (`time_stamp_0`).

You can fix that by adjusting the UDF or by casting the field into an `Int`:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._

val final_df = df.withColumn(
  "features",
  toVec4(
    // casting into Timestamp to parse the string, and then into Int
    $"time_stamp_0".cast(TimestampType).cast(IntegerType),
    $"count",
    $"sender_ip_1",
    $"receiver_ip_2"
  )
)
```

I must say I would expect a proper excpetion and not `null` result, but apparently that's the current behavior.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I got some errors on: TimestampType and IntegerType. I think I should add other libraries. What kind of libraries should I added further the one you mentioned in the answer?

Comment: Added the missing import to the post